# Goals in Google Analytics. A new user registration goal

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

I need to create a goal `A user has been registered` in **Google Analytics**. What I did:

1) I went to `Admin` -> `Goals`

2) Created a new goal with the following details:

[image]

But. This goal is successfull even if a user visited only `/?from=adwords`. But I also need the second URL - `/account/registrated/`. A user must firstly visit `/?from=adwords`, then he can visit any other pages, and then he must visit `/account/registrated/` as a **required** URL.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to track registrations from adwords?

Comment: @XTOTHEL from all sources, not just from AdWords.